# How to add a duration to datetime in Python polars

Tags: python, datetime, duration, timedelta, python-polars

I want to add a duration in seconds to a date/time. My data looks like

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "dt": [
            "2022-12-14T00:00:00", "2022-12-14T00:00:00", "2022-12-14T00:00:00",
        ],
        "seconds": [
            1.0, 2.2, 2.4,
        ],
    }
)

df = df.with_column(pl.col("dt").str.strptime(pl.Datetime).cast(pl.Datetime))
```

Now my naive attempt was to to convert the float column to duration type to be able to add it to the datetime column (as I would do in `pandas`).

```py
df = df.with_column(pl.col("seconds").cast(pl.Duration).alias("duration0"))

print(df.head())

┌─────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────────┐
│ dt                  ┆ seconds ┆ duration0    │
│ ---                 ┆ ---     ┆ ---          │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64     ┆ duration[μs] │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2022-12-14 00:00:00 ┆ 1.0     ┆ 0µs          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 00:00:00 ┆ 2.2     ┆ 0µs          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 00:00:00 ┆ 2.4     ┆ 0µs          │
└─────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────────┘
```

...gives the correct data type, however the **values are all zero**.

I also tried

```py
df = df.with_column(
    pl.col("seconds")
    .apply(lambda x: pl.duration(nanoseconds=x * 1e9))
    .alias("duration1")
)
print(df.head())
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ dt                  ┆ seconds ┆ duration0    ┆ duration1                           │
│ ---                 ┆ ---     ┆ ---          ┆ ---                                 │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64     ┆ duration[μs] ┆ object                              │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════╪══════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2022-12-14 00:00:00 ┆ 1.0     ┆ 0µs          ┆ 0i64.duration([0i64, 1000000000f... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 00:00:00 ┆ 2.2     ┆ 0µs          ┆ 0i64.duration([0i64, 2200000000f... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-14 00:00:00 ┆ 2.4     ┆ 0µs          ┆ 0i64.duration([0i64, 2400000000f... │
└─────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

which gives an object type column which isn't helpful either. The [documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/timeseries/parsing_dates_times.html) is kind of sparse on the topic, any better options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** The values being zero is a repr formatting issue [that has been fixed with this commit.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/commit/51be57604fbc6b193c0aa81285dcab799bd24d7f)

[`pl.duration()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.duration.html#polars-duration) can be used in this way:

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("dt").str.to_datetime()
   + pl.duration(nanoseconds=pl.col("seconds") * 1e9)
)
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────┐
│ dt                      ┆ seconds │
│ ---                     ┆ ---     │
│ datetime[μs]            ┆ f64     │
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════╡
│ 2022-12-14 00:00:01     ┆ 1.0     │
│ 2022-12-14 00:00:02.200 ┆ 2.2     │
│ 2022-12-14 00:00:02.400 ┆ 2.4     │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: it actually is just a repr problem, thanks for pointing me to that!